# Extract value from file for input into IF Statement

Tags: bash, shell

I have a config.txt file where the first line has a number 1, I need to read this and do certain tasks based on whether the number is 1 or 2 or 3 etc

The problem is I cannot test that config value, none of the if statements below work, and I tried many more variances.

```
config=$(head -n 1 /mnt/writable/config.txt)    #grabs vale from file
echo $config        #prints 1
```

But the following if statements do not echo anything.

```
if [[ "$config" = "1" ]];
then
  echo "is a 1";
fi

if [[ "$config" == "1" ]];
then
  echo "is a 1";
fi

if [[ "$config" = 1 ]];
then
  echo "is a 1";
fi

if [ $config = 1 ];
then
  echo "is a 1";
fi
```

I also tried "declare -i config" at the top but that didnt work either. Spent a day and no luck so far.

Comment: All of those checks should work. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It is likely that `$config` contains invisible whitespace, like a `\r` carriage return. Try `cat -A <<< "$config"` to check. Does `file /mnt/writable/config.txt` report that the file has DOS line endings?

Comment: Assuming you are using bash, first thing to do would be place set -xv at start of the script and check what values are actually being set and tested.  You are setting the variable to the entire line, so any additional whitespace will also be assigned to variable, hence it will not be equal to "1".  I would suggest using read to get the value in the variable and then use (()) to test the value against the number 1 :- (( config == 1 )), as numbers are tested this way and makes it clear you are performing an arithmetic test.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for that info, it was a whitespace that caused all my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have space or tab in your first line( I think )

So if you print using

```
echo $config
```

it will print 1 correctly but when you use it in if condition, it may not work as your wish ...

so I suggest that you should try following in your script,

```
config=$(head -n 1 /mnt/writable/config.txt | tr -d '[:space:]')
```

and all your if condition may work.

Comment: Hi Prem, thanks a lot for that, your trick worked brilliantly, all of the statements ended up working.

Answer (score -1):

Integer equality can be tested by using -eq option.

Do man test for further details about if condition.

```
if [ $config -eq 1 ]; then  echo "config is 1"; else echo "config is not 1"; fi
```

Comment: That's true, but a string check will work just as well here.